# Golfing postgres how can I return count number from the query

Tags: go

I am very new to Golang and am using the PQ package for postgres. What I am trying to do is prevent duplicate emails, so I have a query that checks to see if a user email is already in the database

```
check_duplicate_emails, err := db.Prepare("select count(*) from profiles where email=$1")
    rows, err := check_duplicate_emails.Exec(email)

        if rows != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(w,"Duplicate Email")
    }
```

That is my code above how can I make it such that I can check like this

```
if rows >0 { ...}
```

when I try to do that I get the error

> invalid operation: rows > 0 (mismatched types sql.Result and int)

How can I solve this issue as I been looking around to resolve it for a bit now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [the documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Rows), you need to call `rows.Next()` and check that it succeeds:

```
if rows.Next() {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Duplicate Email")
}
else if rows.Err() {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Oops, error %s", rows.Err())
}
else {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "OK, unique email address")
}
```

If there is no data, `rows.Next()` will return `nil` - `rows.Err()` should also be called to check for errors.

Please also note [the other answer from BJ Black](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39736696/1270789) - the `check_duplicate_emails.Exec(email)` line is also wrong.

Answer (score 3):

What's happening here is that you've told Go that your query won't be returning any rows (see [docs for Exec()](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Exec))

You should probably use either:

- a combination of [QueryRow](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.QueryRow) and [Scan()](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#NullFloat64.Scan) (example in QueryRow is a good one), or
- a "select somecol from ... where ..." **without** the count(*) query with [Query](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Query) and look at the rows.Next() to see if there was a first row.